# Advanced key reconfiguration under Linux

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, linux

I'm transitioning to Emacs and trying to reconfigure the layout in a way that reduces the strain on my fingers. One thing I would like to have is the following behavior, which I was told is impossible to configure within Emacs: If the AB04 key is pressed once, it should send a "period" signal, but if the key is pressed and held, it should act as if Crtl is pressed and held. Similarly for AB06 and Meta.

I have customized my keymap, so I have some experience editing it, but I really don't know how to tell the system to distinguish between pressing a key once and keeping it held. Any ideas?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I found that using "god-mode" really helps as I can move around without using meta keys. https://github.com/emacsorphanage/god-mode If you're not into Vim and won't use evil-mode, this is a simpler and easier way to avoid pinkies...

Comment: This should never have been migrated from Super User, because it's 100% true that you can't configure that behaviour within Emacs.  Mods, please send this back to Super User where it belongs.

Comment: Not within emacs, but might be possible via: https://github.com/alols/xcape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [dual-function-keys](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/dual-function-keys), which was very useful for improving my keyboard configuration in general.